# php code to upload multiple images

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

i have two **tables**

**product and productimage table..**

i want to insert multiple images in product image table.

below is my controller code...

the code is working but it is only uploading single image...in my table..

But i want to upload multiple images..i amusing cakephp 2.x

plz help me to resolve this...

```
public function addProduct() {

            if (is_uploaded_file($this->request->data['Product']['file']['tmp_name'])) {
                $pathToUpload = "img/Frontend/Products/" . $this->Auth->User('Profile.user_id') . '/';
                $pathToUploadThumbnail = "img/Frontend/Products/" . $this->Auth->User('Profile.user_id') . "/Thumbnails/";
                if (!(is_dir($pathToUpload))) {
                    mkdir($pathToUpload, 0777);
                    mkdir($pathToUploadThumbnail, 0777);
                }
                $fileName = $this->request->data['Product']['file']['name'];
                $ext = pathinfo($fileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                $this->request->data['Product']['file_name'] = $this->request->data['Product']['title'] . time() . '.' . $ext;
                $fileName = str_replace('/', 'A', $this->request->data['Product']['file_name']);
                move_uploaded_file($this->request->data['Product']['file']['tmp_name'], $pathToUpload . $fileName);
            }          

            if ($this->Product->save($productData)) {
                $this->loadModel('ProductImage');
                if (!empty($this->request->data['Product']['file_name'])) {
                    $productImage['ProductImage']['product_id'] = $this->Product->getLastInsertID();
                    $productImage['ProductImage']['image'] = $fileName;
                    $this->ProductImage->save($productImage);
                }

                $this->Session->setFlash('Product has been added.');
                $this->redirect('productListing');
            }
        }
}
?>

**photo upload button**

<?php
echo $this->Form->input('Product.file', array('type' => 'file','label'=>false,'div'=>false,'class'=>'input_bar'));
?>
```

**I am using below script to generate browse button**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#more').on('click', function(){
        var newfield = '<div class="keyword"><input type="file" class="input_bar" name="data[Product][file][]"><button class="add_more_img btn btn-lg btn-primary update remove">Remove</button></div>';
        $('#main').append(newfield);
    });
    $(document).on('click','.remove', function(){
        $(this).parent('div').remove();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37981807/cakephp-3-multiple-file-uploading-returns-string-instead-of-array/37983795#37983795)

Answer (score 0):

Ello, mate.
You can arrange your product images into an array, such like:

```
$data_to_save = array(
    array('data' => 'value', 'data' => 'value'),
    array('data' => 'value', 'data' => 'value')
);
```

And then you call the method **saveMany()** instead save()

```
$this->ProductImage->saveMany($data_to_save);
```